# ASP.NET MVC 4 An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4 When I'm trying to run my program that problem always pop up.

[image]

```
public class UsersService
{
    // Db Connection string
    string DBCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCon"].ConnectionString;

    //View users list
    public List<UsersModel> All()
    {
        List<UsersModel> _UsersModel = new List<UsersModel>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBCon))
        {
            //call stored procedure
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUsers", conn))  
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    UsersModel _UserModel = new UsersModel();
                    _UserModel.UserID = int.Parse(reader["UserID"].ToString());
                    _UserModel.Firstname = reader["Firstname"].ToString();
                    _UserModel.Middlename = reader["Middlename"].ToString();
                    _UserModel.Surname = reader["Surname"].ToString();
                    _UserModel.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();

                    _UsersModel.Add(_UserModel);
                }
            }
        }

        return _UsersModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is obvious, you don't have SP named with GetUsers ?

Comment: What is SP? Sorry I'm newbie in c#

Comment: As error message says "You have no GetUsers procedure in database, or your connection string is different than you want"

Comment: You have a comment on the line man, it is stored procedure.

Comment: Search google,"What is SP and why,how should I use it".

Comment: This question's title should be renamed (e.g. *"ASP.Net Could not find stored procedure"*) and added tags `sql-server` and `ado.net`. I've edited the question but my edit was rejected by OP.

Answer (score -1):

there is a problem with the connection to the database. The main reason for this... sorry, it could be a network issue, firewall, rejected port, wrong details, etc... What I would do: try try and catch to manage the exception and see the error that you are getting, 
For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Comment: It has nothing to do with the connection - the exception clearly shows that the `GetUsers` SP does not exist

Comment: I don't think so, if there was a connection problem, there will be an error on `con.Open();`

Comment: -1 This is so wrong. The `Exception` message explicitly states the problem. Why do you think this has anything to do with the connection is beyond me.